# Filter for taxonomy term view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

If I create a view for content types, then the filter allows me to display selected taxonomy terms on the view. Right now, I need to create a view for taxonomy terms and their related fields, but I only want to show some of them. When I select the filter of Taxonomy Term: Term, I do not get the option to select the terms I want displayed.

[image: screenshot]

After I choose is one of, there is no option to choose is one of what. Is this a bug or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, I managed to get it to work. Turns out sort criteria has to be defined before the terms will show up.

Answer (score 0):

When you create filter "Taxonomy term: term" there's first step you are choosing "vocabulary" and "selection type" of the filter. It looks like vocabulary you have chosen has no terms.

Comment: Actually the vocabulary does have terms in it. I did find out the issue though, turns out there must be a sort criteria before the terms will show up. I am unable to post an answer to my own question yet, I will do so when I can tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

can you filter that by writing `php` code??
I would use `views php`
module, and add a `php field` that have been excluded from the view, and filtering logic goes there by values provided with this module.
I myself haven't encountered any problems yet, but it's a *red* module in drupal. be aware!

Answer (score 0):

I did it inserting the taxonomy term *field* first, with settings: *Exclude from display*. Then you can have it to set in the *filter criteria*.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, this happened to me after renaming a content type that was referenced by an existing view, then subsequently trying to filter that view by a tax term field on the content type I'd renamed. Same symptoms: I could filter by vocab but when asked whether I wanted to allow terms to be one of or all of, etc., there was never an opportunity to say what term(s) I wanted to filter by.

In my case, the solution was as simple as flushing the cache. :)